# Rails Debugging

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a Rails 2 app, in development everything works fine but in production one of my views is broken and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the cause.

The only difference between development and production is that for some reason development uses the `mysql2` gem and production uses the original `mysql` gem.

First off, if I tail the log, the error I get is:

`ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method 'map' for #<Mysql::Result:0xb5ce7844>) on line #15 of app/views/logical_interface/create.rhtml:`

Line 15 is

```
<%= select_tag 'logical_interface[vlan_id]', options_for_select(@vlan_numbers.map(&:reverse)) %>
```

Which is defined in the Controller as

```
@pop_id = session[:pop_id]

@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = 'Untagged') OR pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id = " + @pop_id.to_s)
```

I checked the `@pop_id` to see if it was failing because it was nil etc but printing it out shows the correct value.

If I remove line 15 and add `<%= @vlan_numbers.inspect %>` all I get is `#` and if I do `debug @vlan_numbers` I get `#<Mysql::Result:0xb5db1298>` so I am genuinely stumped.

I had a look to see if there was anything in `mysql2` that wasn't in `mysql` but all I could find is that `mysql2` is just generally better.

Any ideas?

**Update**

```
@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = 'Untagged') OR pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id = " + @pop_id.to_s).collect { |r| r['vlan_number'] }
```

I tried using the above as suggested my mbratch (answer has now been removed) but it's a bit peculiar because the `Untagged` option that is added to the list has it's text revered so that it's `deggatnU`. I think the same is happening to the select values (which looks like they are just the text instead of the actual `id` from the table).

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by your assertion that *for some reason development uses the mysql2 gem*. You should have control over which gem your development environment uses to make it more like your production environment. Does your `config/environment.rb` say anything about the `mysql` gem?

Comment: nothing in `config/environment.rb`. I just mean I'd expect both gems to be the same and also for production to use `mysql2` seeing as it's 'better'

Comment: When going to production, you may or may not have control over what's on that server (if, for example, you go live on heroku). So sometimes you have to match development to production. But if you control both, then you can set your `config/environment.rb` according to select the right gem.

Comment: it's defined in `database.yml`, `production:
  adapter: mysql`, `development:  
  adapter: mysql2`

Comment: See my updated answer. I think you needed `[id, val]` pairs, not just a list of `val`. I didn't see your explanatory comment until I posted my first revision.

Comment: Back to the environment difference, I'd probably strive to have production be `mysql2` or development be `mysql`, unless there's a specific development reason to have them be different.

Comment: yeah, I agree. I just started here and didn't even know Rails so I'm learning on the job and will probably update production to use `mysql2` once I've fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on what @Vimsha gave, you could try this which will create an array (list) of `[id, vlan_number]` pairs:

```
@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT vlan_number, pop_vlans.id FROM pop_vlans WHERE (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = 'Untagged') OR pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id = " + @pop_id.to_s).map(&:values)
```

And get rid of the `.map(&:reverse)` on line 15.

If you want to make it truly independent of the order that the `SELECT` produces, then slightly longer-hand:

```
@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT vlan_number, pop_vlans.id FROM pop_vlans WHERE (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = 'Untagged') OR pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id = " + @pop_id.to_s).map { |r| [r["vlan_number"], r["id"]] }
```

Comment: thank you, it's __almost__ perfect. An example select option now is `<option value="id4098">vlan_number3</option>` but I don't want the `id` in the value or the `vlan_number` in the text, any ideas how to fix that? I realised about the `reverse` method just as you posted so I've got rid of that now. I could probably use jQuery to fix the vlaues and option texts but that would just be a complete hack.

Comment: @martincarlin87, I not totally sure, but think the reason for that is because your data item is `logical_interface` but the value is an `id`, so it gives you `id4098` since it's not really a `logical_interface` value. What are you really selecting (and wanting the user to set in the db) using this element? Are you selecting a logical interface, or selecing a vlan_id which corresponds to a logical interface? If the latter, then I'd use `select_tag vlan_id...` and label it as "Logical interface".

Comment: I am getting the `vlan numbers` in my `logical interface` controller as there is a one-to-one relationship and I need the user to be able to select a `vlan number` (table is `pop_vlans` to be even more confusing) whose `id` (`vlan_id`) is stored as a foreign key in the `logical_interfaces` table. So rather than dumping `vlan ids` in a select I am trying to show the user something more meaningful, aka the `vlan_number`.

Comment: It sounds like the value you want to return is the `vlan_number` then, if that's what the attribute is in `logical_interface` that you're setting. So it would be `select_tag :vlan_number...`.

Comment: hmm, still the same using `<%= select_tag :vlan_number, options_for_select(@vlan_numbers) %>` but the main reason I need to name it `logical_interface[vlan_id]` is because I am submitting to the `logical_interface_controller` so the rest of the form fields are also  `text_field "logical_interface"` etc.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Can you check to see if the `pop_vlans.id` is really just a number or is it `idXXXX` (or maybe you already know...)? I don't think you need to specify the controller/table name in a `select_tag`. If the view is for `logical_interface` then it would be superfluous.

Comment: @mbirch, definitely just a number.

Comment: @martincarlin87 ok, I didn't do the `map` correctly for what your view wants. Give the updated answer a try.

Comment: hmm, it appears to be the same as before

Comment: OK that's quite puzzling. Can you examine `@vlan_numbers` to see if it looks like an array of elements like `['vlan_number', id]` where `id` is just a number?

Comment: this is the first line from `inspect`ing it - `[[["vlan_number", "3"], ["id", 4098]], [["vlan_number", "4"], ["id", 4099]], [["vlan_number", "5"], ["id", 4100]], [["vlan_number", "6"], ["id", 4101]], `

Comment: @martincarlin87 that's the issue. Are you sure you're using the latest update to my answer? I wouldn't expect it to look like that. What you're showing still looks like `.map(&:to_a)`.

Comment: ah, now that I've refreshed your answer looks different :/ Just tried it and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and patience, I'm sorry that you can only get an upvote and accept from me as you deserve a lot more!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36891/discussion-between-martincarlin87-and-mbratch)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because @vlan_numbers is a Mysql::Result object and not an array. If you want to get an array, do this

```
@vlan_numbers = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT pop_vlans.id, vlan_number FROM pop_vlans WHERE (pop_id = '" + @pop_id.to_s + "' AND vlan_number = 'Untagged') OR pop_vlans.id NOT IN (SELECT logical_interfaces.vlan_id FROM logical_interfaces) AND pop_id = " + @pop_id.to_s)
```

Comment: thanks, using your answer I get this different error `ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method 'reverse' for {"id"=>"12289", "vlan_number"=>"Untagged"}:Hash) on line #15 of app/views/logical_interface/create.rhtml:`

Comment: also, using that on dev also breaks it.

Comment: `select_all` returns an array of attribute hashes. What do you want it to look like to process it? You might need to massage the output of `select_all` a little in Ruby to get what you need. Also, what do you mean by "using that on dev also breaks it"? You need to be specific about what "breaks" means. :)

Comment: yeah, sorry. I just seem to get the same error on dev - 'ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `reverse' for {"vlan_number"=>"3", "id"=>4098}:Hash) on line #15 of app/views/logical_interface/create.rhtml:` all I want my eventual select menu to look like is a list of `vlan id | vlan_number`s from a table named `pop_vlans`